# session not recognized in application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, c#-4.0

In my scenario I have logged into an application and am calling a c# function to create a session in my Identity application. Then I am accessing an service provider application which will redirect to identity application. but here the session I have created is not been recognized and Identity asks Login.

Is my logic correct. or need any remedy?

thanks,
Anish.

Answer (score 1):

It should work but there are a few reasons why your session might be lost:

- The session cookie is expiring - how long before user is redirected back? Check your session timeout
- You are using cookieless sessions - the session identifier in the URL is lost after redirect
- You are using the default in-memory session provider and you have more than one webserver -  you are redirected to a different host that doesn't recognize your session

If it is none of these, use browser developer tools to check the session cookie and see why it isn't being sent.

Comment: I think the 3rd point matches.. First application say 'A' call an ajax request to an MVC action method from there httpclient.GetAsync("http://identity.hmetrix.com/api/Login/PartnerSP?userName=" + activeUser.Name) this call initiates a session in application 'B'.Then 'A' call the api of aplication 'C' which redirects to application 'B' for single sign on. But the session created in 'B' is not recognized and asks for login. How can I do this.

Comment: ASP.NET session state for not carry between sites. I think the "single sign on" session is different from what I was describing about session state.

Comment: If i try to create a session in 'B' from 'A' by ajax request and then call 'C' it works but it takes too long time may be due to cross domain. Is there possible remedy.